# What external power supply should I use for Arduino modules?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ac-dc

I build a data logger with Arduino MEGA, SD, Ethernet, RTC, GSM, display module, and thermal printer. I am facing problem with unregulated power supplies. I have tried many power adapters, phone chargers, led strip power supplies and noone is 5±0.2V regulated. All power supplies are over 5V and are drifting overtime. I tried led power supply with buck converter 5V and the output was 5.4V. The only good power supply was ATX PSU but it is waste of money.

I need a 5V 2.5-3A regulated power supply, how can I find or build one?

Note: The device is going to work continuously over 5 years

Comment: On the commercial market you can find plenty of proper power supplies. Since you want to work over 5 years you not only need a power supply but also power backup and an alarm system.

Comment: What is the total current requirement?

Comment: @Decapod I have already build backup system with alarm notification with sound and call on phone.

Comment: A High-quality Phone Charger power-supply such as those made by Apple or Samsung **MIGHT** last many years.  Or maybe not.  Inexpensive (no-name Asian) supplies probably will NOT.

Comment: Actual supply voltage is usually not critical.  Most stuff designed for 5V operation will happily run from a supply voltage of 4.5 - 5.5 Vdc.  Check the specs of **ALL** of the equipment and devices running from that supply.

Comment: @DwayneReid peaks may are 3amps, on sleep mode are (say) 10mA.

Comment: I dont trust phone chargers because they are not regulated. I tested some old nokia, motorola chargers and they were over 8V

Comment: How did you test the output voltages of the power supplies? Simply placing a multimeter across the output is no good as a supply may be designed for a a certain minimum load.

Comment: Yes I tested with no load, I hope it is 5V volt stable with minimum load.